# Is there a term for permutations where the elements are optionally included?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The permutation for `abc` would be:

```
abc acb bac bca cab cba
```

But if the elements are optional:

```
"" a b c ab ba ac ca bc cb abc acb bac bca cab cba
```

Is there a term for when we include the elements optionally?

Comment: It could also be seen as the permutations of decreasing combinations, but I am not sure if that is the right way to phrase the question.

Comment: In the semigroup literature, these are "partial" transformations (which are one-to-one).

Answer (score 0):

In semigroup theory there is the notion of *partial transformations* on a set $X$ which are, roughly, self-maps of $X$ defined only a subset of $X$.  This allows you to (again, roughly), speak of all functions into $X$ whose domain is any subset of $X$, and to speak of them all at once.   What you have are the **partial injections** on $\{a,b,c\}$.  Alot of this is central to the theory of inverse semigroups.